# Install Shapely on Windows 10

Tags: python, pycharm, shapely

I need your help for installing Shapely. The project where I work is on PyCharm and I need to install Shapely to compile the project:

> from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPolygon, asShape

I've tried to install it from the interpretor (Settings > Interpretor > +) but it says me that

> "WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found".

So I decided to install it from the command line. I think that I've Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 installed on my Windows 10 laptop (Python --version returns Python 2.7.12 and python3 --version returns Python 3.5.2). I executed the following line:

> import pip._internal; print(pip._internal.pep425tags.get_supported())
>   [('cp27', 'cp27m', 'win_amd64'), ('cp27', 'none', 'win_amd64'),...]

When I run from my Download folder (where the .whl is)

> pip install Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

I have the following message error:

> Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I have Python 2.7 (cp27) and my pip supports win_amd64. I don't really know what I can do now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173474/discussion-between-flyingteller-and-nelly-barret).

Answer (score 3):

Try using `conda install shapely`, that helps avoid breaking your packages as well.